# Python get GenericRelation objects

Tags: python, django, object, generic-relations

I have the following code:

**data/telephone.py**:

```
class TelephoneNumber(models.Model):

    MOBILE = 0
    HOME = 1
    TELEFON_CHOICES = (
        (MOBILE, _("Mobile")),
        (HOME, _("Landline")),
    )

    object_id    = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    of           = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id' )

    label = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=TELEFON_CHOICES) 
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

**model.py**:

```
class Staff(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    telephonenumbers = GenericRelation(TelephoneNumber, related_query_name='telnumber')
```

No I want to provide a function to retrieve every telephone number of a user like this:

```
def get_telnumbers(self):
    tellist = []
    #print(self.telephonenumbers.all())
    for tel in self.telephonenumbers.all():
        tellist.append(tel)
    return tellist
```

The problem is, that the line `print(self.telephonenumbers.all())` does not print any telephonenumbers, even though a lot have been provided.
The returned dict is empty as well.

How can I access the GenericRelation objects saved within the `Staff` context?

**Edit:**

The following code:

```
for tel in TelephoneNumber.objects.all():
        print(tel)
        print(tel.of)
```

gives me every telephone number saved, and through `tel.of` the right staff user which the telephone number belongs to.

So why isn't `self.telephonenumbers.all()` working (`self.user` also returns the right user for which the telephone number should have been saved)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure why `self.telephonenumbers.all()` is not working.

But I am using this (kind of ugly) workaround now:

```
def get_telnumbers(self):
    for tel in TelephoneNumber.objects.all():
        if tel.of.id == self.id:
            ...
```

If someone still has a better idea, I am open to that!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when creating a new `TelephoneNumber` object you provide `content_object` attribute to be the corresponding `Staff` object

Comment: could you give a short example of how to do that? thanks

Comment: Look at this example at djangodocs  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation  Hope this helps.